# emberjs force .find() to search for new data on server

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

My situation is I have a rendered {{each}} opened and then open a modal for a new entry as an overlay. with .findAll() my table updates when i save my new entry with my needed .find() not..

I need to reenter my route to get new data:

```
return this.store.find('user',{filter:{where: {role: 'abonnent'}}});
```

Syncs perfectly with my api, but I can't append parameters:

```
return this.store.findAll('user');
```

I would like to use it like so:

```
    import Ember from "ember";

    export default Ember.Route.extend({
      model:function(){
        return this.store.find('user',{filter:{where: {role: 'abonnent'}}});
        //return this.store.findAll('user');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `store.filter` or `store.all` if you need "auto-updated" filters. `store.filter` and `store.all` are live filters from the store, while `store.find` is returning a promise resolving to whatever the server is going to answer at that point.

Quoting from ED docs of `DS.Store#filter`:

> Takes a type and filter function, and returns a live RecordArray that
>   remains up to date as new records are loaded into the store or created
>   locally.

Here is how I'd write my route:

```
model: function() {
  return this.store.find('user', {
    filter: {where: {role: 'abonnent'}}
  });
},
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, this.store.filter('user', function(record) {
    return record.get('role') === 'abonnent';
  }));
}
```